# How to add data sync (Google docs) ability to iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, synchronization, data-synchronization

I would like to enable my iPhone app's data to sync with Google docs.  How can this be done? What other sync'ing options do I have (another one I am aware of is EverNote Sync Server)?

Answer (score 1):

try [nutdb](http://www.nutdb.com) app for iphone. nutdb will sync every nutdb database with google docs hosted spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give a specific answer without more detail, but Google does provide an [API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/overview.html) that allows some manipulation of document data.  The [httpriot](http://labratrevenge.com/httpriot/) library is a handy way to simplify access to REST structured web services like this.